# version OPENSSL_1.0.2 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

I am trying to setup old version of rails(3.2.17) and ruby(1.9.2). When I try to start up the rail server, I am getting the following error:

`require': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: symbol SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos, version OPENSSL_1.0.2 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

When I run openssl version, its 1.0.2g

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Standard OpenSSL 1.0.2 does not provide versioned symbols (this has changed in the 1.1.0 version). Debian based systems have a patch to OpenSSL that versions the symbols. If libcurl is linked against the debian version of OpenSSL, and you have the standard version (i.e. downloaded directly from the OpenSSL website) then possibly this could be your issue?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio the link doesnt address the question